# when I have already added "Id" in the R.java fire , and run my project the "id" that I have added before are all cleaned up automatically

Tags: java

- When I run my "app" ,It always prompts me "File was loaded in the
  wrong encoding:'UTF-8'
- when I  have already added  "Id"  in the R.java fire ,and when I run
  my project  the "id" I have added before are  all cleaned up
  automatically.

  ```
  @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  ViewHolder holder;
  Log.i("SJM22", "" + "###999_");
  Log.i("SJM1", "getView -- " + position + " -- " + convertView);
  if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);
      GridView.LayoutParams param = new GridView.LayoutParams(
              LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
              height);
      convertView.setLayoutParams(param);
      holder = new ViewHolder();
           /*�õ������ؼ��Ķ���*/
      holder.layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
      holder.leibeiname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1_1);
      holder.total = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1_2);

      holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image1);

      convertView.setTag(holder); //��ViewHolder����
  } else {
      holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); //ȡ��ViewHolder����
  }
  ciyuLeibie = list.get(position);

  try {

      String pic = ciyuLeibie.getPicurl();

      holder.image.setImageBitmap(getImageFromAssetsFile(context, pic));

      Log.i("SJM11", "yes");
  } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  Log.i("SJMSJM", ciyuLeibie.getName() + ciyuLeibie.getPicurl() + ciyuLeibie.getTotal());
  holder.leibeiname.setText(ciyuLeibie.getName());

  holder.total.setText(ciyuLeibie.getTotal() + "");

  holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          //Toast.makeText(context, "SJSJSJ", 0).show();
          Intent intent = new Intent(context, CiyuconentListActivity.class);

          intent.putExtra("CiyuLeibie", list.get(position).getName());
          context.startActivity(intent);
      }
  });
  return convertView;}

    /*��ſؼ� ��ViewHolder*/
    public final class ViewHolder {
     LinearLayout layout;
     TextView leibeiname;
    TextView total;
    ImageView image;}
  ```

**Please find the links to screenshots below:**

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq58g.png [2]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3ftE.png

Comment: formatted the code.

Comment: fixed the question statement

Comment: The project is so huge and I couldn't do that.

Comment: Have you tried loading the file in another encoding? There is even a button to do so, in the upper right corner